# VBA code in excel for mac

Tags: macos, vba, excel, module

I am trying to create a module in excel for mac. I need to add it in the VBE but am unable to figure out how to do so. If anyone has information that could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate that a lot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search found this question asked [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2016-macexcel/visual-basic-support-in-mac-2016/4afbba04-4435-4970-8b02-40da006a590e?auth=1). Consensus is that the feature isn't available (and there aren't plans to make it available). The recommendation is to use the features In Office 2011 or on a Windows machine (with 13 or 16).